# Java Serialization Behavior

Tags: java, serialization

I'm going through serialization and I can't understand the following:

I don't understand why the output of this code is:

```
import java.io.*;

public class InnerOuterTest {
    public static ObjectOutputStream out;
    public static ObjectInputStream in;

    static {
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("save.ser"));
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("save.ser"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            ShouldForgive f = new ShouldForgive();
            f.x = 5;
            write(f);
            ShouldForgive g = read();
            System.out.println(g.x);
            f.x = 0;
            g.x=8;
            write(f);
            ShouldForgive v = read();
            System.out.println("is "+v.x);
        } finally {
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private static void write(ShouldForgive f) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(f);
    }

    public static ShouldForgive read() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        return (ShouldForgive) in.readObject();
    }
}

class ShouldForgive implements Serializable {
    int x = -1;
}
```

Is

```
5
8
```

And not

```
5
0
```

I tried `f == g` which returns false and if I reset the input stream. I found out that if I implement `readObject` it is only called once... I don't understand this behavior. (Why is the object only read once?)

I get the feeling that serialization only happens once... How is the object tracked? Even if I implement `readObject` and `writeObject` without actually reading or writing from the file I still get `8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `out.reset()` after the first write, you will get the behaviour you are expecting, or if you use `writeUnshared()` instead of `writeObject()`. Objects that have already been written to the stream are not rewritten; instead a 'handle' to the previously written object is written. See the Javadoc for details.

Answer (score -1):

OK...I think i got it...

1. **During serialization**, its **NOT the object which is serialized, but its Instance variable...
   as extracted and stored.** For an object its instance variable is everything...
2. So during de-serialization, the **same instance variables are inflated back**, and using those 
   instance variable value, an **Another Identical object is created on the heap..**
3. If you check the **hashcode of both these objects, they will be different.**

Thats causing the above behaviour mentioned by you.

Either follow this sequence

```
f.x = 0;
g.x=8;
```

or this

```
g.x=8;       
f.x = 0;
```

**Still the result will be 8, cause its now a completely different object on the heap with different instance variables.**

**Edited part**

`The below code will print f as 5..... for both the sysout`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            ShouldForgive f = new ShouldForgive();
            f.x = 5;
            write(f);
            ShouldForgive g = read();
            System.out.println(g.x);

            f.x=0;
            write(f);
            ShouldForgive v = read();
            System.out.println("is "+v.x);
        } finally {
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not quiet clear. If they are two different objects, how write "f" writing value "8"?

Comment: The hashcodes are quite likely to be the same if the object is well written.

Comment: Not the correct answer. And the hashcodes can still be the same if the objects are different instances.